# By/Within two minutes

Tags: prepositions

For example, you can say:

> Within two minutes of the game

But you can also say:

> By two minutes of the game

Which is correct? Are they interchangeable? If they are not interchangeable, what is the difference?

Comment: You can't say _by two minutes of the game_. You might say _by two minutes **after** the game_ (naming a particular time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we use "by [a particular day / date / time]" and "within [a duration]" when referring to deadlines. So, your first sentence is correct.

The definition of "by" is:

> 4. indicating a deadline or the end of a particular time period.
>    "I've got to do this report by Monday"

The definition of "within" is:

> 3. occurring inside (a particular period of time).
>    "tickets were sold out within two hours"

*(all definitions from Google)*

---

However, if you are referring to a change in time, you may use "by":

> 1. The opening time was moved forward *by two hours*.
> 2. The opening time was extended *by two hours*.